# Terminating a Java Thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I can see this question being asked lot many times. Apologies for asking this again. I have a weird problem.

I have a job that submits thousands of jobs through ExecutorService as separate Runnable task. This is done in a simple for loop. End of for loop, I call service.shutdown() and followed by awaitTermination.

Because number of threads to be submitted is huge, threads keep hanging till all tasks are submitted.

Is there any way, these threads can be terminated gracefully as soon as its execution is finished?

Comment: If you are calling `ExecutorService.shutdown()` the ExecutorService will stop all its threads (by allowing them to return from their run methods) when all jobs are completed.

Comment: Thanks Dev. Is there any way to shutdown the thread as soon as its execution is complete instead of waiting for all other threads to finish?

Comment: The job running thread or threads execution is not complete until the `ExecutorService` is shutdown. Threads are usually reused for multiple jobs. If you want to shutdown the `ExecutorService` after a specific job has completed you can block on the `Future` for that job and `shutdownNow()` the executor when it returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new `ThreadPoolExecutor` without calling `java.util.concurrent.Executors`:

```
    int corePoolSize = 0;
    int maximumPoolSize = 64;
    int keepAliveTime = 5000;
    ExecutorService executorService =
            new ThreadPoolExecutor(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime,
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new SynchronousQueue<Runnable>());
```

From the javadoc: "If the pool currently has more than corePoolSize threads, excess threads will be terminated if they have been idle for more than the keepAliveTime"

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html

**Edit:**

Here is a small example, if you run this in Eclipse debug environment you should see the threads coming and going:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class ExecutorTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ExecutorService executorService = new ThreadPoolExecutor(0, 64, 1000,
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new SynchronousQueue<Runnable>());

        for (int i = 0; i <= 500; i ++) {

            try {
                Thread.sleep(new Random().nextInt(200));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }

            executorService.submit(new TestTask());
        }
    }

    public static class TestTask implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(new Random().nextInt(1500));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: KeepAilveTime did not work for me. I was under impression that after say 30 second that I specify as keepAliveTime, the eclipse debug environment should not show the thread running. But that did not happen. I still see the thread live, although it is not processing. I know that thread should be harmless, but I don't want too many dangling threads in my app. Am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe your `corePoolSize` parameter is too high?

Answer (score 0):

It is correct that `shutdownNow()` would let you abort execution with pending tasks.  If your goal is to do just enough work to compute some result (which will take an undetermined number of tasks), but stop doing more work as soon as you have the result, then you will need some way for the `Runnable` objects to signal to the loop that it should stop looping.  Something like:

```
ExecutorService svc = ...
AtomicBoolean done = new AtomicBoolean();
for (int i=0; i < jobs.length; i++) {
   svc.submit(new MyRunnable(done, jobs[i]));
   if (done.get()) break;
}

class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
   private final Whatever job;
   private final AtomicBoolean done;
   MyRunnable (AtomicBoolean done, Whatever job) { this.done = done;  this.job = job; }
   public void run() {
     if (done).get() return;
     //do the work
     if (somehowComputeThatTheWorkIsComplete) done.set(true);
   }
 }
```

If things are hanging because too many threads are being launched, then consider using [Executors.newFixedThreadPool()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool%28int%29) - the computer cannot actually do more work concurrently than the number of logical cores available.  So using an unbounded thread pool (can create up to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` threads) is not useful, because it doesn't actually get you more concurrency.  Just limit the executor to a reasonable number of threads and "hang" types of problems will probably disappear.

Comment: Thanks Tim. This is exact same problem you mentioned. I don't want to keep the threads that have completed their execution alive. Each thread is already gathering required results in separate collection and those threads are no longer needed. So even if I use fixedThread, it is still going to wait for other threads to finish before terminating.